# Creating an exception for opening external links in new windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, hostname

I am using a simple Jquery script to force `target="_blank"` on all external links. The problem is that it opens up subdomains in new windows. I want to adapt this code so it allows for subdomains in the same browser session versus forcing a new window.

For instance, if my site was on http://pixeltest.com and I had a link to http://test.pixeltest.com, that would open up in a new window.

The Code:

```
$("a").filter(function() {
    return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
}).attr('target', '_blank');
```

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
```

to

```
return this.hostname && this.hostname.substr(this.hostname.indexOf('.')) !== location.hostname.substr(location.hostname.indexOf('.'));
```

this should only then compare everything after the first dot.

Comment: what if there is no"dot" meaning its not a subdomain, but rather a normal external link. WIll it still work in that case?

Comment: ah, yeah this could get tricky if no 'www.' is included. you will have to do some fiddling around with the code to make sure it works in all of your use cases, perhaps only applying the above code if more than one dot is contained in the host.